# Реализовать проверку редактирования страницы другим пользователем

Tags: javascript, php

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно по простому реализовать проверку редактирования страницы другим пользователем. Допустим я открыл страницу и реадктирую ее. В этот момент другой пользователь открывает эту же страницу пишет туда что-то и сохраняет, но потом я тоже сохраняю страницу и тем самым перезапишу его труды. Как можно по простому реализовать проверку таких случаев, что бы если я уже открыл редактирование этой страницы, то другому пользователю при открытии редактирования этой страницы выдавалось уведомление, что эту страницу уже редактируют.

П.С. лично я сам пока придумал только вариант, когда при открытии редактирования страницы в БД у записи этой страницы в специальное поле ставился мой ID и при сохранении страницы он удалялся. И при открытии другим пользователем этой страницы если мой ID там есть, этому пользователю выдавалось уведомление, но есть проблема. Ведь я могу начать редактировать страницу, потом передумать и тупо закрыть браузер. Но мой ID останется и другие пользователи не смогут редактировать.

Все это дело желательно реализовать на php и js

Подскажите пожалуйста самый просто вариант решения данной проблемы

Comment: Резервировать за собой - неправильно. А то ты открыл и ушёл на обед... человеку надо, а он вместо корректировки тебя ждать будет. Некрасиво. Правильно - перед записью твоих "трудов" получать страницу ещё раз и сравнивать с тем, что было получено на редактирование, и при несоответствии сообщать, что "за время Ваших трудов страница была изменена".

Comment: @Akina еще хуже, работаю я такой 2 часа, потом хочу сохранить, а она уже изменилась, и что делать? 2 часа в пустую?

Comment: @ThisMan Каким образом? Человек же описал что при редактировании оно "резервируется" и не будет доступно другим

Comment: @InDevX я про вариант Akina когда резервирования нет

Comment: @ThisMan понял, туплю.. Но, так же, там было написано о сравнении результатов, нет? Этакий гит на минималках

Comment: @InDevX не знаю, на сколько механизм мерджа можно считать "простым", как этого хочет автор

Comment: @ThisMan *работаю я такой 2 часа, потом хочу сохранить, а она уже изменилась, и что делать? 2 часа в пустую?* То есть СВОИ 2 часа впустую - это плохо. А ЧУЖИЕ - когда кто-то два часа ковыряет в носу, пока ты работаешь - это нормально? *и что делать?* У тебя есть текущее состояние. У тебя есть твоё откорректированное состояние. Сливай. Да, придётся ещё поработать - но тот, кто внёс правку, ничем не хуже тебя. Кто первым встал... это, по крайней мере, честнее. Так у тебя крадётся немного времени на мерж. А при резервировании ты у другого человека крадёшь ВСЁ время, которое работаешь сам.

Comment: Вообще, самый просто вариант - сделать как ТС написал, установить временное ограничение и сделать возможность продления. Нажал кнопку и +15 мин или что-то в этом роде. Но, опять таки, это больше на костыли смахивает и не особо приемлемо, как и написал @Akina. В идеале, конечно же, реализовать механизм мерджей, но тот кто это сможет сделать вряд ли будет задавать тут вопросы)

Comment: @Akina думаю тут надо еще спросить, что именно подразумевается под "редактированием", только текст? Либо это именно добавление, удаление, изменение, перестановка каких то блоков структурных. Мердж такого редактирования и в ручную то может быть не простой задачей. Но, в общем случае, мердж кажется единственным правильным решением.

Comment: @ThisMan Автоматический мерж - это и вправду геморрой, соглашусь. Идея тайм-аута - неплоха. Но ещё лучше - не хочешь "два часа работать, а потом дорабатывать"? сохраняйся сам в явной форме каждые 5 минут. Спасение утопающих... а если кто-то вклинился, так за 5 минут наработано немного, мержить куда как проще, чем всю двухчасовую работу. Всё-таки правильнее, когда каждый сам куец своего счастья...

Comment: Спасибо всем. прочитав коммент от @InDevX. Меня натолкнуло на мысль. Сделать так: пользователь А открывает страницу и в специальное поле у этой записи пишется его ИД, а так же еще в специальное поле пишется время в timestamp момента открытия статьи. И потом в фоне каждые 10 сек аяксом это время обновляется. И если при открытии страницы пользователем Б это время отстает на 15 секунд(то есть уже 5 секунд не обновлялось аяксом пользователя А), то его ИД и время перезаписывается на ИД и время пользователя Б. Я думаю это достаточно просто и то что мне надо. Всем спасибо

Comment: @MisterX каждые 15 сек отправлять запросы не лучшый вариант.. Если хотите так сделать - смотрите в сторону web sockets

Comment: @InDevX пожалуй да. Подумаю еще, но на крайняк думаю сделать и аяксом. Все равно пользователей будет 20-30 человек в день :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант -- блокировка (то, что вы и описали). Для блокировок лучше создать отдельную таблицу. Вы можете хранить там не только id пользователя, который захватил блокировку, но и время до которого блокировка захвачена, атрибуты клиента (например редактирую из дома и на работе). Это позволит решить некоторые проблемы с ожиданием.

- Захватывайте блокировку на небольшое время и автоматически продляйте её при активности пользователя.
- При отсутствии активности можно вывести сообщение о том, что блокировка будет снята через 10, 9, 8... с кнопкой "Я просто задумался".
- Закрытие окна (вкладки) браузера обрабатывайте на клиенте и делайте запрос на снятие блокировки.
- Пользователям ожидающих освобождение блокировки сообщайте кто её захватил (если это не противоречит каким-то идеям работы приложения), возможно они смогут договориться.

Начните с простого и наворачивайте фичи по ходу дела. Возможно вы столкнётесь с неочевидными проблемами. Например кто-то будет захватывать много документов и это будет сердить остальных пользователей или кто-то будет редактировать (действительно внося правки) документ очень долго. Или ещё что-то.